# Get data from html (url)

Tags: javascript, php, html

we want to create a script that gather data from url.

I have read a lot about this in internet, but cant manage to make it work.

The data i need to get is a key that is found on a specific url.

```
playlist: '/get_file.php?stream=WyJPRUU1TkRWRk5VUXpSVFJGUXpFM1FUb3hNemcxTWpFME5Ua3lMamMzTlRRNlpHWTBZV00wTUdVNU16ZzJObVZqTkdFNU9HSXdaVEptT0dGaE5XUmhaREUzTUdVd09UUTJaZz09IiwicmVnIl0=',
```

i need that long key that is after `**stream=**` and ends with

```
',
```

we saw some examples, like:

```
<?php
  $link = file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com");
  $file = strip_tags($link, "<div>");
  preg_match_all("/<div/>(?:[^<]*)<\/div>/is", $file, $content);
  print_r($content); 
?>
```

but its not our case.
Please help us to get this data from url,
thnx for reading.

Comment: how are you getting the url?

Comment: I'm inclined not to answer, because it looks like you're attempting to subvert a website's content protection measures. Can you explain why you're doing this, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: hello,we have tried $link = ile_get_contents("http://www.domain.com");

Comment: @squeamishossifrage, we have tryed some examples but with nor results. please can you help us to get the code after stream= ? pls

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'www.example.com';
$url .='/get_file.php?stream=WyJPRUU1TkRWRk5VUXpSVFJGUXpFM1FUb3hNemcxTWpFME5Ua3lMamMzTlRRNlpHWTBZV00wTUdVNU16ZzJObVZqTkdFNU9HSXdaVEptT0dGaE5XUmhaREUzTUdVd09UUTJaZz09IiwicmVnIl0=';
$queryArray =  parse_url($url);
```

the stream argument will be contained within

```
$queryArray['query'];
```

This will be an array if there is more than one argument

```
var_dump($queryArray);
```

To see all its options

See here [php parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Working Example

```
<?php
$url = 'www.example.com';
$url .='/get_file.php?stream=WyJPRUU1TkRWRk5VUXpSVFJGUXpFM1FUb3hNemcxTWpFME5Ua3lMamMzTlRRNlpHWTBZV00wTUdVNU16ZzJObVZqTkdFNU9HSXdaVEptT0dGaE5XUmhaREUzTUdVd09UUTJaZz09IiwicmVnIl0=';
$queryArray =  parse_url($url);
echo $queryArray['query']."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";
var_dump($queryArray);
?>
```

will return

```
stream=WyJPRUU1TkRWRk5VUXpSVFJGUXpFM1FUb3hNemcxTWpFME5Ua3lMamMzTlRRNlpHWTBZV00wTUdVNU16ZzJObVZqTkdFNU9HSXdaVEptT0dGaE5XUmhaREUzTUdVd09UUTJaZz09IiwicmVnIl0=


array(2) { ["path"]=> string(28) "www.example.com/get_file.php" ["query"]=> string(155) "stream=WyJPRUU1TkRWRk5VUXpSVFJGUXpFM1FUb3hNemcxTWpFME5Ua3lMamMzTlRRNlpHWTBZV00wTUdVNU16ZzJObVZqTkdFNU9HSXdaVEptT0dGaE5XUmhaREUzTUdVd09UUTJaZz09IiwicmVnIl0=" }
```

Comment: hello, the stream= is inside the html file not in url. thnx.

Comment: if you are grabbing  just the stream part then add a fake url to the start then parse it

Comment: also it can be found inside a A href tag, like this one.

<a href="/get_file.php?id=8A945E5D3E4EC17A&key=WyJPRUU1TkRWRk5VUXpSVFJGUXpFM1FUb3hNemcxTWpFME5Ua3lMamMzTlRRNlpHWTBZV00wTUdVNU16ZzJObVZqTkdFNU9HSXdaVEptT0dGaE5XUmhaREUzTUdVd09UUTJaZz09IiwicmVnIl0=&original=1" class="download_file_link" target="_blank" style="margin:0px 0px;">Download File</a>

Comment: we dont know the key after stream=, also it is found inside the html file..i get nothing with your example, what is wrong ?

Comment: the problem is that i need that key.. that is changed on every url. please read my question, that key is inside a html.. i have used your example but dont return what i am looking for.

Comment: parse the html, get the string your looking for , assign it to a variable like $string, and on the second line of my example change it to $url.=$string; and do this for each string you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could try preg_match:

```
$found = preg_match("/stream=(.+)'/", $html, $match);
if ( $found ) {
    echo $match[1]; 
}
```